# In UITableviewCell,How to call user created function in viewdidload() instead of calling in awakefromnib()

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have used collection view inside UITableView .Whenever I scrolled up, top most cell reloaded.

[image]

Comment: Any code you have done yet?

Comment: @jackjay... inside tableview cell override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        getAllCategory()
    }
    
    func getAllCategory()
    { }

Comment: tableview cell don't have any viewDidLoad() method as such, its method of viewcontroller.

Comment: You can call this function in your UITableViewController's `cellForRow(at:)` method. [see here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow)

Comment: #vivekdas...thats what my prob is..I hv create one function &call it in awakefromnib() which is called so many time

Comment: @jackjay...it doesn't work...still it reloaded every time while scrolling

Comment: Sorry but i dont get what are you trying to achieve and whats the issue you are having? Could you edit your question please?

Comment: https://medium.com/anantha-krishnan-k-g/pull-to-refresh-how-to-implement-f915743703f8